# How do I run my node.js application on a client's server without sharing the codebase with them?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, enterprise, saas

We are using Angular for front end and Node.js for backend. We are in conversation with a client to run our application on their local server, hence if we could use a package executable of the application, it would not give them access to our source code. We want to know if there are any robust tools that can help us do this or if there is any other way in which we can allow them to use all our application's offerings without giving them any idea of how the application works technically.

Comment: Hey, this doesn't seem a good fit for SO, which is a site for questions about programming related topics. This is more fit for ServerFault. Btw, anything you do to secure your code will not work against a determined adversary. You're stuck with the honour system; which usually works pretty-well actually.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have next options

1. compiles your backend part into a single executable file [nexe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nexe)
2. encode your critical parts to weird format [weird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsweird)
3. run your backend part in docker after minifier/compressor tool [minifier](https://javascript-minifier.com/nodejs)
4. compiles modules to binary format [binary](https://gist.github.com/YaroslavGaponov/f2a8f30e433e4471eb8f2531eb9f5fff)
5. mix all options